# flutter image picker reduce file size with provider and flutter_image_compress

Tags: flutter, provider, imagepicker

I am using image picker to pick image from device(App) and after that stored that file in provider class like that.

```
  File? _img;
  get img=> _img;
  void putbannerimg(File img) {
  _img = img;
  notifyListeners();
  }
```

I found out that image picker does not compress png images, I tried compressing it with flutter_image_compress

```
compressFile() async {
final formservice = Provider.of<PostForm>(context, listen: false);

File file = formservice.bannerfile;

final result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
  file.absolute.path,
  quality: 54,
);
formservice.putbannerimg(File.fromRawPath(result!));
```

}
I tried this way And other multiple ways but getting different different errors I want to upload this file in firebase storage like this

```
    var task = storageicon.putFile(formservice.iconfile);
```

please tell me where I am going wrong, without compress file all things are working fine

**Edit: I found out that path should be a string how can I parse local code file in that**

Comment: Can you please tell us what error you getting?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Also post all the functions mentioned in your original post, not just what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "[flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)" package

You may have to use the compress function for files stored on the phone like this:

```
Future<File> testCompressAndGetFile(File file, String targetPath) async {
var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    file.absolute.path, targetPath,
    quality: 88,
    rotate: 180,
  );

print(file.lengthSync());
print(result.lengthSync());

return result;
```

}

"compressAndGetFile()" returns a file while "compressWithFile()" returns a Uint8List.

If i understand your last question right, you want to use an image built into your application by default.
For this, you have to open your "pubsepc.yaml", go to the "flutter:" mark and add "assets:" like so:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - path
```

"path", in my example, describes a top level folder containing assets like pictures.
You can freely describe its name.